# Кто работал с Oauth2 от Goolgle?

Tags: oauth, php, google-app-engine

В моем случае не ясно, где получить следующие параметры:

```
user: '{username}',
    clientId: '{Client ID}',
    clientSecret: '{Client Secret}',
    refreshToken: '{refresh-token}',
    accessToken: '{cached access token}' // optional
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо зарегистрировать приложение на сайте проектов [вот здесь есть пример](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)
Там вы получите все что нужно, но еще нужно знать как все получать вот ссылка в помощь - [тык](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)